# Tucker-Eric/EloquentFilter Laravel

Tags: laravel

Good day! I'm currently using a laravel package `Tucker-Eric/EloquentFilter`. I want to know if what is your approach in filtering Brands of an Item.
I have tables `Brand` and `Items`. And `Item` belongs to `Brand` and the `Item` is the one using the Eloquent Filter. In my frontend, I have a scenario where if I type name of the items, all items will be displayed. Also if I type brands name, all items with that brand will be displayed. Thanks in advance. Btw here's my ItemFilter Code

```
public function name($name)
{
    return $this->whereLike('name', $name);
}

public function brand($brands)
{
    return $this->whereIn('brand_id', $brands);
}

public function category($categories)
{
    return $this->whereIn('category_id', $categories);
}

public function type($type)
{
    return $this->whereIn('type_id', $type);
}

public function max($price)
{
    return $this->where('srp', '<=', $price);
}
public function min($price)
{
    return $this->where('srp', '>=', $price);
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

Change your Query in `brand function`.

```
public function brand($brands)
{
    return $this->whereHas('brand', function ($query) use ($brands) {
                        $query->whereIn('id', $brands);
                    });
}
```

the `item` model `belongsTo` relationship should be `brand`.

Comment: Note that in my frontend I also have a sidebar for list of brands. That is why I am using whereIn because its passing an array of brand Ids.

Comment: is the `brand` request is an array of ids? not string?

Comment: Yes sir, it's in array. And I do have a search bar for name but i also want that I search for brand name, it's related item will also appear

Comment: My brands are working sir. And I do have a search bar where customers can input either name, brands or categories of items and will result to items matched.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use the [`related`](https://github.com/Tucker-Eric/EloquentFilter#filter-related-models-with-the-related-method) method in the filter. You can add a `brandName` method and `brand_name` query parameter to pass that data to `related`.

All together it would look like: `/my/url?brand_name=some+brand`

```php
public function brandName($brandName)
{
    $this->related('brand', 'name', $brandName);
}
```

Or if you want to do a `whereLike` on the name for the `brand`:

```php
public function brandName($brandName)
{
    $this->related('brand', function($query) use ($brandName) {
        return $query->whereLike('name', $brandName);
    });
}
```

The `related` method will collect all queries to that relation and wrap them all in one `whereHas` query under the hood for all calls to the related model in that filter.